# Similar variable or files name in Programming

Tags: php, laravel

I mostly work with similar named variables, routes and files in Laravel/Php. as `stock in`, `stock out` or `available stock`. I defined view names in Laravel for them as following.

`stock_in.blade.php`
`stock_out.blade.php`
`stock_available.blade.php`

I use this pattern in the sense that the file/route is about `stock` so it should come first (It will be easy to trace/find them, related files will be in one place). Because `in`, `out` and `available` are general words can be attached in other files too as `in_stock`, `in_account` or so on.

1. So is it good practice to name files/routes as I'm naming?
2. Can I use the same pattern for `variables` name?

Comment: If it does not throw error, then you can use it. I would put files to folder named `stock` and name it `in.blade.php`, `out.blade.php`... That way you have more dynamic, changing only folder name will change view

Comment: @Justinas how/when it could throw error?

Comment: not sure how clear this question is ... personally, I'd have stock.php file. The variable would be $stockStatus and this is a int (0 = out of stock, 1 = in stock etc.) and control it that way .... I think this may be down to personal pref

Comment: Did you consider making folder stock then put all the blade files in this folder?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs let suppose you have to create three files, in_stock(this is the file which will process when new products get in stocks), out_stock(this is the file which will process when products sold out or go out of the stocks), available_stock(this is the file which have detail about how many products are available). So how would you name them? `in_stock`, `out_stock`? or stock will come first.

Comment: @abdulla_malik yes I did that. But what about route names? or let suppose you can't create folder or you need all files without folder then?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq that's what I'm saying, I'd just have a `$stockType` which links to a `in_stock` in the database, 0 = out of stock, 1 = in stock. Then with this I just need one template and conditionals ... but that's how I'd do it - I'm sure others would take different paths, hence I reckon this is opinion based

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs let me explain in other sense, suppose you want four files to Add Products, Add Account, View Products, View Account. how will you name them? add_products? or products_add?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq oh ... in that sense, I'd personally do `action_module` - e.g. `create_product` || `list_product` || `view_product` etc. though I'd also use Folder based generic stuff. E.g. Folder called `Product` with controller called `AddController.php` which calls `templates/product/add.twig.html` (example uses Symfony - but concepts remain the same across frameworks etc.)

Comment: Interesting: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/blade-naming-conventions

Comment: As for route use middleware.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs thanks and what about route names?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq more or less same principle - so `Product/AddController.php` would link to route `/product/add/` - so it's `/module/action/`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs no I mean route name not route path. As `Route::view('current-orders', 'current_orders')->name("current_orders");`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs `Route::view('current-orders', 'admin.merchandise.current_orders')->name("merchandise_current_orders");`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I'm assigning name to each route to easily use in blade templates to add in `href`.

Comment: @AsifMushtaq Oh I see, erm not sure - I used the conf files rather than declare Route:: above controller (down to my preference) - but I'd probably still try to match route name to route url, just instead of `/` I'd use `-` so `module/action` becomes `module-action` - again this is all down to my opinion - should be taken with a grain of salt - there may be way better ways of doing it, this is just how I "logically" (in loose quotes) see it

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs how you can match the url and the route name? any example? `product/add` this is url and route name will be what?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq the name would be product-add

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs last question, `product` is folder and `add`, `edit` `view` are files in that folder to add, edit and view specific product. So what will be file name for view all products? `all` ? or `index` ?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq I personally just call it `list` :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs sorry for one more question, and url will be? `product` or `product/list` ?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq `product/list` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182078/discussion-between-asif-mushtaq-and-thisguyhastwothumbs).